# How do you put a parameter on a complex type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have one class:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private T start;
    private T end;
```

In another class, I have:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {  
    Range range=(Range)target;//Eclipse complains about unparamterized type
    if (range.getStart().compareTo(range.getEnd())>0){ //This gives an error if I do Range<?>
```

Now, Eclipse gives a warning about range being a raw type.  If I replace it with (`Range<?>`) then I get an error, presumably because it makes it not know about the parameterization on the type.  If I do `<? extends Comparable>`, I still get the warning because I didn't parameterize Comparable.  Is there a good way to get rid of the warning?

Should I just do a @SuppressWarnings?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to specify the actual type in instantiations?

Comment: Why not `validate(Range<T> target,Errors errors)`?

Comment: @CharlesWood you are supposed to do that, but there are no instantiations just a cast.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `(Range<? extends Comparable<Object>>)target` but there would still be the unchecked cast which you'd need to suppress using `@SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )`.

So if you can change the method signature to use `Range<T>` instead of `Object` I'd do that.

Answer (score 2):

This variant gives no warning (though I'm not sure why the compiler even needs this hint, as it could/should know that by the definition on Range):

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void validate (Range<T> range, Errors errors) {
    if (range.getStart().compareTo(range.getEnd()) > 0) {
```